# Apps requesting access to the All files access permission without a permitted use will be removed from Google Play, and you won't be able to publish

Tags: google-play

Apps requesting access to the All files access permission without a permitted use will be removed from Google Play, and you won't be able to publish updates.

This is the bit that's unclear, at least to me. So if an app is currently in the Play Store but targets API 29 and has requestLegacyExternalStorage=true, will that app be removed from the Play Store in the future? If so, that's bad. I get that after November for any updates the target API must be 30.

We received this warning what does it means, we use requestLegacyExternalStorage flag and targetsdk 29, so my app will be removed from play? And what changes i need to do for this?

Answer (score 4):

No, your app is not get removed from playstore...

but your app not might work if you targeted API 30 above. "requestLegacyExternalStorage=true" is a temporary solution provided by google to allow developer to smooth transition to new Secure Storage Model.

Many apps that had no legitimate need to read all the files stored on the device’s storage were requesting this permission, causing Google to narrow storage access permissions with Android 11’s “Scoped Storage” changes.

You have two option:

1. If your app require little to moderate use of storage > [Use “Scoped Storage”](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9577211-scoped-storage-in-android-10-getting-started#toc-anchor-004)
2. If your app is such as File Manager,Anti-virus,etc in which required all storage file access to work effectively and efficiently > [Use "All files access"](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access)

Further query [link_1](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-11-all-files-access-permission-form/) , [link_2](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955)